# Any way to create page preview on hover?

Tags: docusaurus

In our docusaurus knowledge base we are building we are wanting to do some Wikipedia-style page preview effects on hover. I've seen a few ways to do it, but not any that would work in Docusaurus. Is there any way to do this well?